# Sphinx morphology and suggestion not working together

Tags: sphinx

I've enabled morphology with lemmatizer and it returns correct result for this situation:

I have not `journalist` keyword indexed and instead the `journalists` exists. The morphology helps us to search by `journalist` because it is the singular form of existed keyword.

But when I want to call suggestion on the `journalist` keyword, it will not return this word for suggestion because it doesn't exist and the morphology has not been enabled on it.

The result will be these existed keywords:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => {#603 ▼
    +"suggest": "journalism"
    +"distance": "1"
    +"docs": "2"
  }
  1 => {#604 ▼
    +"suggest": "journalists"
    +"distance": "1"
    +"docs": "1"
  }
  2 => {#605 ▼
    +"suggest": "journals"
    +"distance": "2"
    +"docs": "1"
  }
  3 => {#608 ▼
    +"suggest": "journeys"
    +"distance": "4"
    +"docs": "2"
  }
]
```

Is it an issue with sphinx or my application?

Comment: Think you need to explain your problem more. What you show seems to correct, as you say journalist is not used in index, so wouldnt be returned by `CALL SUGGEST`. What are you 'hoping' would happen?

Comment: I think the whole scenario is that i explained. Ive used morphology to return result for `journalist` because it is not indexed but it is singular forms of indexed keyword `journalists`.
But this will not work in suggestion. I want to find a way to do this. I have a search engine to show the results for `journalist` and a section to show the suggestion for other keywords. but in this case I should not get any suggestion because I have result for it.
hope the explanations are enough.

Comment: Sorry, no I still dont understand what asking. Hopefully someone else does.

Comment: If I'm right you mean by having morphology enabled both cases of journalist and journalists should be considered as a right keyword when only one of them is indexed not like it's normal behaviour when morphology is disabled and suggestion considers only the indexed keywords. Unfortunately I don't have any solution for.